# preg_match for a string that contains a comma and a space

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a scrip that extract logs of our web application from a txt file. There was no problem extracting logs until a value with a comma was entered in our database recently. I am currently using preg_match for matching a pattern of strings and one of it is as follows:

```
preg_match("/\[params\] (.*?) \[/i", $record, $regs);
```

The above is used to match content in our logs text file such as:
[params] customer: Shangrila Shanghai Pudong, poi_id: 14747, language: en...(I have no problem in matching that. Recently an entry was made in such a way that the string contains a comma. For example:

```
[params] customer: Shangrila Shanghai, Pudong poi_id: 14747, language: en
```

I assume because of the comma the preg_match does matching only till "Shangrila Shanghai". As a result of this I am unable to extract logs for that particular customer. I already changed the entry in the database to avoid such a problem in the future but I need to extract logs for the previous months.

I am a beginner for regular expressions and have been scratching my head to fix this. What can be changed to match the whole pattern "Shangrila Shanghai, Pudong" instead of just "Shangrila Shanghai"?

I hope I am being clear and any help is highly appreicated. Thanks in advance.
Here is the block of code:

```
foreach ($files as $filename)
    {
        $path = "$root/../request_archive/$filename";
        $extracted = "$root/../request_archive/$filename.temp";

        $fh = fopen($extracted, "r");
        $count = 0;
        while (!feof($fh))
        {
            $line = fgets($fh);
            if (preg_match("/^\[id\]/", $line))
            {
                $count = 0;
                $record = $line;
            } else {
                $count++;
                $record .= $line;
                if ($count > 1)
                {
                    // echo "count: $count\n";
                    // echo "\n\n$record\n\n";
                }

                if (!isset($regs[1]) || $customer_name != $regs[1])
                {
                    preg_match("/client: (.*?),/i", $record, $regs);
                    if (!isset($regs[1]) || $customer_name != $regs[1])
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                preg_match("/\[command\] (.*?) \[/i", $record, $regs);
                $log_command = $regs[1];
                preg_match("/\[params\] (.*?) \[/i", $record, $regs);
                $content = $regs[1];
                preg_match("/\[request_time\] (.*?) \[i", $record, $regs);
```

> [command] search [params] customer: Pudong Shangri-La, keywords: bar
>   rough, nearby poi: 18270, record_limit: 20, page: 1, language: cn,
>   ip_address: *.*.*.* [headers]
>   a:44:{s:10:"GEOIP_ADDR";s:13:"";s:20:"GEOIP_CONTINENT_CODE";s:2:"AS";s:18:"GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE";s:2:"CN";s:18:"GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME";s:5:"China";s:12:"GEOIP_REGION";s:2:"23";s:17:"GEOIP_REGION_NAME";s:8:"Shanghai";s:10:"GEOIP_CITY";s:8:"Shanghai"

Comment: I don't think the regular expression you provided matches the string that you claim that it matches. Are you sure your question is correct?

Comment: Yes I am sure the question is right I can provide the block of code and a block of the text.

Comment: That would be useful because at the moment your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your regex with this test data, it works perfectly fine.

```
$record = '[command] search [params] customer: Pudong Shangri-La, Shanghai keywords: bar rough, nearby poi: 18270, record_limit: 20, page: 1, language: cn, ip_address: ..*.* [headers] a:44:{s:10:"GEOIP_ADDR";s:13:"";s:20:"GEOIP_CONTINENT_CODE";s:2:"AS";s:18:"GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE";s:2:"CN";s:18:"GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME";s:5:"China";s:12:"GEOIP_REGION";s:2:"23";s:17:"GEOIP_REGION_NAME";s:8:"Shanghai";s:10:"GEOIP_CITY";s:8:"Shanghai"';
preg_match("/\[params\] (.*?) \[/i", $record, $regs);
echo $regs[1];
```

It shows

> customer: Pudong Shangri-La, Shanghai keywords: bar rough, nearby poi: 18270, record_limit: 20, page: 1, language: cn, ip_address: ..*.*

which matches exactly from `[params]` until `[headers]`, including commas and colons.

If you want to extract the customer name only, try this one based on your example string

```
$record = '[command] search [params] customer: Pudong Shangri-La, Shanghai keywords: bar rough, nearby poi: 18270, record_limit: 20, page: 1, language: cn, ip_address: ..*.* [headers] a:44:{s:10:"GEOIP_ADDR";s:13:"";s:20:"GEOIP_CONTINENT_CODE";s:2:"AS";s:18:"GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE";s:2:"CN";s:18:"GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME";s:5:"China";s:12:"GEOIP_REGION";s:2:"23";s:17:"GEOIP_REGION_NAME";s:8:"Shanghai";s:10:"GEOIP_CITY";s:8:"Shanghai"';
preg_match("/\[params\]\s*customer:\s*(.*?)\s+keywords:/i", $record, $regs);
echo $regs[1];
```

Comment: yes it would work fine but I have an entry for example: "customer: Pudong Shangrila, Shanghai" where "pudong Shangrila, Shanghai" is the name of the customer. That has to match the entry in the database but I assume it matches only "pudong shangrila" and it doesn't match with the entry in the database. So "customer: pudong shangri-La" is fine but I want "customer: pudong shangri-la, shanghai" to be matched when there is a comma in the customer's name

Comment: @Uday Do you want to extract the customer's name? If yes, you asked the wrong question.

Comment: Nope, I am sorry If am not being clear. I appreciate for your time. What I am trying to say is that I want to modify the preg_match so that in case if there is a comma value in the customer's name it should be recognized as one string such as customer: "pudong shangrila, shanghai" not as "customer: pudong Shangril_la", shanghai

Comment: @Uday It does already, the comma makes no difference. See the modified answer. I modified `$record` and appended Shanghai after the comma and it shows the whole string including Shanghai and everything until it finds `[headers]`

Comment: For some reason I can't extract the logs and I tried removing the comma in our database and I am able to extract the current logs, but I couldn't do it for the past record coz the text files are already generated and its huge task to extract them again for the previous months. Anyways thanks so much for your time. Really appreciate!

Comment: So I assume the customer name is recognized before the comma. And I am very bad at regex. That'the reason I posted this question here.

Comment: @Uday No, the customer name is recognized *including* ", Shanghai" and everything else until the next `[`. If you want to extract the customer only, you must append another criteria. See the modified answer please.